# git asking for user credentials (Gitlab)

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to do my inital commit on a project. Git online and local repos are already set up and the ssh key should also work properly. I'll use `example.com` as reference for my git server.

When I type `ssh git@gitlab.example.com` I get `Welcome to GitLab, Name Surname!`

When I try to push my first commit `git push --set-upstream origin master` it is asking for user credentials, but I'm not sure where to find those. I got a loginname and password from my company and on GitLab my username is `name.surname`. I tried both combinations loginname/password and username/password but both say

```
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.example.com/name.surname/project.git/
```

Later on I want to achieve the connection directly in Visual Studio, but there happens the same, when I want to push something, it's asking for user credentials.

Comment: Did your project-lead / company give you the right permissions for you? Did he give you the right login information ?

Comment: @Rick_Jellema I can login to the GitLab website on the server with the loginname. I created a own git online repo and wanted to test with that

Comment: Hmm, alright, Then I'd almost think it might have to do with the connection from your IDE's to the git repo. do you have your own GitServer or do you use the Gitlab website itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your remote (`origin`) is set to the `https` URL instead of the `ssh` URL.

See the output of `git remote show origin`.

You can change the URL using:

```
git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.example.com:name.surname/project.git
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit the config file inside the .git folder and change the url directly in the editor:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@gitlab.example.com:name.surname/project.git
```